# How to count the value of timer in VB

Tags: vb.net, vba, timer, counter

I am using timer in my code. I am setting 1s timer for serial data receive from arduino. Now, I wanted to write into excel file for every 1 min. using timer. Indivually it working fine. Writing into excel for every 1s. But i wanted to write for every 1min.
Below i posted timer code. which is being set for 1s. when 1 s gets over increment counter  and display count value on text box.

If count value reach 60 means 1 min. then write to excel sheet else keep incrementing .

Here is my part of code

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim counter As Integer
        Try

            SerialPort1.Write("c")
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
            Dim k As Double
            Dim value As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
            k = CDbl(distance)
            ListBoxSensor.Text = k

            Dim s As New Series
            s.Points.AddXY(1000, k)
            Chart1.Series.Add(s)
            Count_val.Text = counter

            If counter = 6 Then
                Dim headerText = ""
                Dim csvFile As String = IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "Current.csv")

                If Not IO.File.Exists((csvFile)) Then
                    headerText = "Date& time ,value, "

                End If

                Using outFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(csvFile, True)
                    If headerText.Length > 0 Then
                        outFile.WriteLine(headerText)
                    End If
                    Dim y As String = DateAndTime.Now()
                    Dim x As String = y + "," + value
                    outFile.Write(x)

                End Using
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Or is there any way to calculate the No of time timer being called?>??

Comment: `counter` is a variable which never gets a value. Also, do not do: `Catch ex As Exception   End Try` (empty catch).

Comment: @TimSchmelter How can do this. i found timer i am not getting data from serially for example code.with timer i can write in to CSV file for set no of intervals.

Comment: @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά δι How to get only date. If i call DateAndTime.Now() .It not giving second value.

Answer (score 0):

In your timer tick sub declare *counter* as *static*. Using *Dim* the value scope is local and will be lost after returning. That means in every tick *counter* is always zero. *Static* keeps the value even after returning.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static counter As Integer = 0 'Initial value
    counter += 1 'increase for every tick

    Try
        ...
        ...
        If counter = 60 Then
            ...
            ...
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in Timer1_Tick: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```